# Find records of nearest date SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table `dbo.X` with `DateTime` column `lastUpdated` and a code product column `CodeProd` which may have hundreds of records, with CodeProd duplicated because the table is used as "stock history"

My Stored Procedure has parameter `@Date`, I want to get all `CodeProd` nearest to that date so for example if I have:

```
+----------+--------------+--------+
| CODEPROD | lastUpdated  | STATUS |
+----------+--------------+--------+
|       10 |   2-1-2019   |   C1   |
|       10 |   1-1-2019   |   C2   |
|       10 |   31-12-2019 |   C1   |
|       11 |   31-12-2018 |   C1   |
|       11 |   30-12-2018 |   C1   |
|       12 |   30-8-2018  |   C3   |
+----------+--------------+--------+
```

and `@Date`= '1-1-2019'

I wanna get:

```
+----+--------------+------+
| 10 |    1-1-2019  |   C2 |
| 11 |   31-12-2018 |   C1 |
| 12 |   30-8-2018  |   C3 |
+----+--------------+------+
```

How to find it?

Comment: What happens if a `CODEPROD` has 2 or more rows "closest"? For example, there are rows with the value `20190102` and `20181231` for `CODEPROD` `13`. Should the row for `20190102` or `20181231` be returned? Both?

Comment: @Larnu It should return the record with `20181231`

Comment: By nearest do you mean the smaller one closest to the date or smaller/greater one closest to the date.

Comment: @SalmanA the smaller one, the nearest lower value closest to that date. e.g: if `@Date` is `20190101` and I have `20181231` and `20190102` I wanna get `20181231`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TOP(1) WITH TIES` to get one row with nearest date for each `CODEPROD`  which should be less than provided date.

Try like following code.

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES * 
FROM   [YourTableName] 
WHERE  lastupdated <= @date 
ORDER  BY Row_number() 
            OVER ( 
              partition BY [CODEPROD] 
              ORDER BY lastupdated DESC);
```

Comment: Thank you! One question, bro... Evet if I add ` WITH(NOLOCK)` and the index for `[CODEPROD]` the queryhets time so it's still too heavy to execute. Is there clue how to optimize the SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` :

```
select distinct t.CODEPROD, t1.lastUpdated, t1.STATUS
from table t cross apply
     ( select top (1) t1.*
       from table t1 
       where t1.CODEPROD = t.CODEPROD and t1.lastUpdated <= @date
       order by t1.lastUpdated desc
     ) t1;
```

Comment: Your TSQL work super fast comparing to `PSK` answering with `SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES * 
FROM   [YourTableName] 
WHERE  lastupdated <= @date 
ORDER  BY Row_number() 
            OVER ( 
              partition BY [CODEPROD] 
              ORDER BY lastupdated DESC); `  So thank you very much!